# steganography library in C or Obj-C

Tags: c, objective-c, macos

Does anyone know of a good steganography library I can use thats written in C or Objective-C?  It would need to be used in a Mac OS X application.

Comment: are you sure you mean *stenography*? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stenography , maybe you meant *steganography* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography instead?

Comment: so, what shall it be: stenography or steganography?

Comment: sorry, it was supposed to be steganography

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My provocative answer will be that you should try to implement/learn some algorithms for image hiding/unhiding yourself. Sample algorithm of 3-bit image hiding into 24-bit image is very simple and consists of about 10 Python lines or so (of course it may be a bit more with C/Obj-C). And you will get not bad quality of stego image - about 87.5% of original quality. So check [my blog article](http://coding-experiments.blogspot.com/2010/06/steganography.html) about this steganography method.

This stego decoding method is done in GPU pixel shader program for fast decoding procedure.
However encoding was done with Python script which after use was deleted ;P
But i think that encoding procedure is very straightforward and can be understood from my blog article. If any questions about my stego algorithm- feel free to ask.